# Store Laravel 5.6 Query log in database table

Tags: database, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I want to store Database query logs belongs to Laravel 5.6 application inside a database table. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: That is not a good job and suggest not to do that!if you want to check your query and monitor them using elastic search instead of storing in database

Comment: ```@Hamed``` thank you for your suggestion...

Comment: ```@Kaspars``` that why I ask this question. Already I found a solution for record queries inside the DB table using AppServiceProvider class boot Method. But that particular query also storing and it going as a never ending loop. I want to stop That Problem. Is there any way to do that??